# Scrolling div inside div using link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to scroll to top position of div based `id` when link clicked...
if link beside click so div id "ltv" move / scroll to top..

this my picture to describe my purpose
[image]

if anyone knows how to do this, or can give me a good starting point I'd appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use jQuery's [scrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) function

```
$('#ltv').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#divId').scrollTop(0);
});
```

If you want this to be like a slide up to the top, you can use it with `.animate`:

```
  $('#divId').stop().animate({ scrollTop: "0px" });
```

if you are wanting a certain div to go to the top, you are gouing to have to work out its y offest and then use that as the scrollTop px

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/2kP92/3/)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
$('.links').click(function()
{
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('.section').eq($(this).index()).offset().top }, 1000);
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5nTVn/

Answer (score 0):

This might come in handy:

http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Basically, it's a jQuery plugin that helps you scroll in different ways to different DOM elements.