# How can i make a site like this by myself?

Tags: javascript, css

I saw this type of site : [FireWaves](http://centoragfire.wix.com/firewaves-design-inc) 
I really like the idea of desplaying pages content. The home page is simply the background image and the menu, then when you press on a page frrom the menu, it happends that :
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/mb1Vg.jpg
the menu bar goes down, and the page content appears. I want to use this into a wordpress theme, but don't know how to make this type of site. i guess is a combination of css and ajax, but i'm not sure

Comment: Seriously? that page itself has a link that says "This site was created using  WIX.com.  Create your own for FREE". Maybe that is a good place to start?

Comment: i want to make it bymyself, cuz i wanna use the code into a wordpress theme

Comment: I don't know much about JS, but do you mean something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586819/scrolling-div-inside-div-using-link ?

Comment: i don't think it helps me, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using twitter Bootstrap ([getbootstrap.com](http://getbootstrap.com))
This will help you creating this type of website easily.
Twitter Bootstrap is easy to use and help you making really good and responsive websites.

Cheers!!

Comment: @user3054345 twitter bootstrap is really a very good front end framework to start with. in fact you can design much better web page than you have asked :).. just get your hand dirty on it...